# Parametric bootstrap *prediction* interval with heteroskedasticity and sandwich parameter covariance matrix

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity, prediction-interval

The sandwich estimator for OLS regressions where heteroskedasticity is suspected is
$$
var(\hat\beta) = (X'X)^{-1}X'ee'X(X'X)^{-1}
$$

If I want confidence intervals on predictions, I can just take many draws from $N(\hat\beta, var(\hat\beta))$, multiply by $X$, and take the quantiles.

But what if I want *prediction intervals*?  My model is
$$
y = X\beta + e
$$
$$
e = N(0, \sigma^2 f(X))
$$
and I need to be able to take draws from the error to make a prediction interval.  Is there some trick for getting a prediction interval in such situations without going back and estimating $f$, which would be maybe some sort of two-step conditional heteroskedasticity model?

Perhaps a trick that involves taking on some simplifying assumptions?